# How to list all RALLY-Projects by Kanban board or Scrum board using API?

Tags: java, node.js, rally

I wanted to know the list of projects that uses the **Kanban-Board** , and the list of projects that uses the **Scrum-Board** under a workspace in Rally, suggest me a query that can prepare the result.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to gather metrics on usage of specific apps/custom pages in your subscription.  This would be a neat feature request though.